# ¿como poner un jPanel en un jframe?

Tags: java-swing

quisiera tener un jPanel  dentro de un jframe,el jPanel hay un jText para identificar que si se puso el jPanel en el jFrame, en el jframe tengo un boton y al pulsarlo trato de que se abra el jPanel, cosa qeu no sucede , lo que hago es instanciar al Jpanel en la clase dodne se extiende de Jframe y en el boton utilizo esa instancia.

```
public class VentanaPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

     panelPelota PanelPelota;
    public VentanaPrincipal() {
        initComponents();
         PanelPelota= new panelPelota();
     PanelPelota.setBackground(Color.red);
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     PanelPelota.setVisible(true);
 this.add(PanelPelota);
    }
```

```
public class panelPelota extends JPanel {

    public panelPelota() {
        initComponents();

    }




    @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        super.paintComponents(g);

        Graphics2D graficos2D =(Graphics2D)g;
        Pelota pelota = new Pelota();
        graficos2D.drawLine(200, 200, 500, 500);
    }



    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

varías cosas:

1. **Tu código no declara ni inicializa por ningún lado el JButton jButton1**. Supongo que debe ser un despiste.
2. **Debes añadir al botón una ActionListener**, el cual debe encargarse de gestionar la respuesta a l¡los eventos producidos sobre dicho botón. Con declarar un método void (como tu jButton1ActionPerformed) no es suficiente.
3. **Debes añadir los componentes creados** (tu boton y tu panelPelota) **a tu frame principal**.

Tu código podría ser algo así:

Clase VentanaPrincipal

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class VentanaPrincipal extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    PanelPelota panelPelota;
    JButton button;

    public VentanaPrincipal() {

        initFrame();
        initComponents();
        addComponentsToContentPane();
        addListeners();


        this.pack();
        this.setSize(400, 400);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void initFrame() 
    {
        this.setTitle("VentanaPrincipal");
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);
        //this.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Left"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        //this.getContentPane().add(new JButton("Center"), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        panelPelota= new PanelPelota();

        // Button with text "Register"
        button = new JButton("Tocame");
    }

    private void addComponentsToContentPane() {
        this.getContentPane().add(panelPelota,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.getContentPane().add(button,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    private void addListeners() {
        // add a listener to button
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
          {
              if (!panelPelota.isVisible()) panelPelota.setVisible(true);
              else panelPelota.setVisible(false);
          }
        });

    }

//  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
//      panelPelota.setVisible(true);
//  }
//    
}
```

Clase PanelPelota

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PanelPelota extends JPanel {

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    // End of variables declaration      

    public PanelPelota() {
        initPanel();
    }


    private void initPanel() {
        this.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.setVisible(false);
    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {

        super.paintComponents(g);

        Graphics2D graficos2D =(Graphics2D)g;
        //Pelota pelota = new Pelota();
        graficos2D.drawLine(200, 200, 500, 500);
    }

}
```

Test

```
public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        // Create frame with title Registration Demo
        VentanaPrincipal frame= new VentanaPrincipal(); 

    }
}
```

Comment: graciiiassss, fue de gran ayuda